# How do I use text-to-columns to keep only the final column in Excel?

Tags: excel, delimiter, text-to-column

I'm in Excel and I have a long list of folder directories like you see below. I want to use the forward slash delimiter to only keep only the file name in the directory. The problem is that each directory link has it's own depth of sub-folders that make it tricky to extract just the the file name at the end. Is there a way to do this?

What it looks like now:

../folder1/file1.pdf
../folder1/folder2/folder3/file4.pdf
../folder1/folder2/file3.pdf

What I want it to look like:

file1.pdf
file4.pdf
file3.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILTERXML()` would be good choice in this case. Try-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

You can also use below formula-

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

[image]